# Passing NULL pointer to pointer and expect allocating for main

Tags: c, pointers, split, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I was checking pointer to pointer, passing it without allocating. I want to allocate `a[0]="something str" a[1]="some thing str" a[2]="something str" a[3]="something str"` in `pp` function. Can I do this (allocating and filling with `strcpy` in pp function) and get it returned back to main?

This is my attempt:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100
// float 3
void pp(char *arr, char *delimiter, char **a)
{
    int i = 0;
    *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
}

int main(int argc, void **argv)
{
    char *arr = "1.77 1.65 1.56 5.555 6.1";

    char **f;
    pp(arr, " ", &f[0]);
}
```

I thought I could just allocate individual `char *` and then populate as `strcpy(*(a+x),"something")` but it causes segfaults at `*a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);`.

Comment: `*a=malloc...` should raise a compiler warning about "making integer from pointer...". If not you should increase warning level. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Your segfault comes from accessing `f[0]` which is illegal because you did not assign a value to `f` first. But your whole approach will not work.

Comment: @user786 Are you going to split the source array into an arrays of doubles?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes that what I will eventually do. Basically array that holds float

Comment: Then your description that you want an array of strings (`a[0]="something str"`...) is rather misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple bugs in your code.

You do not initialized `f` but access `f[0]`.

You allocate memory for 10 single `char` but not for pointers in your function.

Also the overall approach is broken.

You could try like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100

void pp(char *arr,char *delimiter,char ***a)
{
// TODO: Handle NULL pointers.

    int i=0;
    // TODO: Calculate number of strings using arr and delimiter...
    int num = 10;
    *a=malloc((num+1) * sizeof(**a));
    for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)
    {
        (*a)[k] = malloc( 1+ length of string to copy) ;
        strcpy((*a)[k], <string to copy>);
    }
    (*a)[num] = NULL; // indicate end of array.
}

int main(int argc,void **argv)
{
    char *arr="1.77 1.65 1.56 5.555 6.1";
    char **f;
    pp(arr, " ", &f);
    int i = 0;
    while (f[i] != NULL)
    {
      printf("string #%d: %s\n", i, f[i]);
      i++;
    }
}
```

You should also think about a way how to report the number of found substrings back to the caller. In the example I added an extra pointer holding `NULL` to terminate the array.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the header `<malloc.h>` is not a standard C header. Instead use header `<stdlib.h>`.

Aa for your task

> yes that what I will eventually do. Basically array that holds float

then you can use the approach shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t split( const char *s, const char *delim, double **a )
{
    *a = NULL;

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( const char *p = s;  p += strspn( p, delim ), *p != '\0'; )
    {
        ++n;
        p += strcspn( p, delim );
    }

    if ( n != 0 && ( *a = malloc( n * sizeof( double ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        char *endptr;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            ( *a )[i] = strtod( s, &endptr );
            s = endptr;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *s= "1.77 1.65 1.56 5.555 6.1";

    double *a;

    size_t n = split( s, " \t", &a );

    if (  a != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%.3f ", a[i] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( a );
}
```

The program output is

```
1.770 1.650 1.560 5.555 6.100
```

Actually the function can be more complicated because you will need to check that conversion to double were suvvessful.

Comment: why in code after \n u assumed there should be \t. is it always there in string literal.

Comment: @user786 The tab character '\t' is also a white space character.

Comment: Ok but like to ask why is it always at the end of string literal? Even as in code u did not specify and assign this to s pointer at end

Comment: This is as this without \t char *s= "1.77 1.65 1.56 5.555 6.1";

Comment: @user786 You always should use a more general approach. What will you do if numbers will be separated by the tab character?